# What do these 将 and 为 mean?

Tags: grammar

警方将小印度一带规划为受管制区，不许任何人在管制区内公共场所喝酒。

Not sure how these 将 and 为 are used grammar-wise. If I were to break it down:

(警方)（将）（小印度一带）（规划）（为）（受管制区）

（police）（towards/把？）(little india) (plans) (???) (area under surveillance)

As a whole I understand that the police plans to put little India under surveillance. Could someone explain the grammar please?

Comment: 将 here serves the same purpose as [把](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C7%8E_construction).

Comment: @InglisBaderson 「將」here is more often seen in written scripts than spoken languages. 「把」 is more informal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

将...+v.+为=把...+v.+当作

这篇报道中提到的”小印度“在新加坡，那里的人使用的中文有自己的标准。这也许就是你查不到翻译的原因。

尽管如此，在报章杂志或者政府公文中，我们一般不说”把...“，而是用更古雅的”将...“来表达。在方言中，”把“一般只在北方方言中出现，南方跟喜欢说”拿“一类的词。对于比中国南方更处于南端的新加坡而言，对”把“的使用是不习惯的。

至于第二部分，"将...规划**为**
"在大陆有时会写成”将...规划**作**
“。”作为“是一个词，这里只是用它的不同简略形式。本文这里这样写是因为古语中视"为"为介词，”作“是动词；但是大陆现代汉语中”作“也可以作为介词，如同在”当作“一词中一样。

---

将...+v.+（作）为=把...+v.+当作=do the (verb) to the object and thus make it into the state of (following text)

Here: The police has **set** the region of Little India **as** Restricted Area where no alchohol can be consumed in public.  (Singapore is famous for weird rules.)

"Little India" in this report is in Singapore, where people speak Chinese in a different style. Maybe that's why you cannot find proper translation.

However, in official texts or newspaper and magazines, we rarely use ”把...“. We prefer ”将...“ because we cannot find any usage of ”把...“ in classical Chinese which makes ”将...“ a more elegant way to put it.

And in dialects, ”把...“ is more commonly used in Northern areas. In the south, we say "拿.." more often. For Singaporeans (and Malaysians) who lives south to Southern China, they are simply not used to such expressions.

For the 2nd part, in mainland, we sometimes write "将...规划**作**
" rather than "将...规划**为**
". That's because both are abbr. from the verb 作为, meaning **being/regarded as**. Here the author picks 为， also because grammar of classical Chinese regard "为" as a proposition and "作" as a verb; but in mainland modern mandarin, we also regard 作 as a proposition sometimes, like in the word 当作.

Answer (score 3):

"为" is "as" here. "Subject + 将 + object + verb" is equal to "subject + verb + object".

So  警方将小印度一带规划为受管制区 is equal to 警方规划小印度一带为受管制区

Answer (score 3):

Both 将 and 为 gives different meanings in different context.

But I think the 将 in the sentence is not read as a single character. It is read as 将.......规划为.  So the grammar is 将.......動詞(some verb) because it will not be a complete sentence if there is no verb follows.

为 here is supporting 规划 like a preposition. It is usually used when you are dividing something, like an area. 一个分为两个.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

In this case 将 is equivalent to 把; both introduce the object and allow it to be placed before the verb.

As for 为, I agree that it can be tricky to analyze here*.  I think two of the definitions that ABC gives for 为, "act/serve as" and "be; become," are the most useful here.  In other words, one might read this part of the sentence as saying that the 警方 plan for 小印度一带 to be/become a 受管制区.  More naturally, we might put this as: the 警方 plan to make 小印度一带 a 受管制区.

* as 为 is taught almost exclusively as part of a limited number of constructions, even though it does have other uses.